# Fortran 90: Repeated elements of a string

Tags: fortran

I want to write a program that tells me how many times appears each letter of a character of some dimension n. For example:

Character(length=4) :: char="hello"

The program must give me:

'H appeared: ' 1 'time'

'E appeared: ' 1 'time'

'L appeared: ' 2 'times'

'O appeared: ' 1 'time'

Here's picture of what I've done, But of course it has some errors and idk how to fix it. For instance, i want it to print each letter only once, but because the write(*,*) is inside the first 'do i=...' each n-repeated letter is printed n times.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSxaM.jpg)

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment and the question is very unspecific. Put your code in a properly formatted code environment (click "help" while editing) and ask a specific question. I.e. how are you trying to solve it and what exactly are you struggling with? Then you might get some help.

Comment: Why are you using Fortran90? Nowadays nobody should be learning that very old standard - at least Fortran95 should be used, or better Fortran 2003. Also please don't put your code in an image, put it in the question - this makes it searchable.

Comment: Of course, `O` appears zero times in the length-four character "hell".

Answer (score 0):

`SCAN`, `INDEX`, `VERIFY` are the most notable Fortran intrinsic functions dealing with character search in strings. For example, this is a case-insensitive working implementation:

```
program test_hello
      implicit none

      character(len=*), parameter :: upperAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
      character(len=*), parameter :: lowerAlphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
      
      call printLettersInWord("hello")

      call printLettersInWord("fortran") 

      contains

      subroutine printLettersInWord(word)
          character(len=*), intent(in) :: word

          integer :: j,letterCount(0:len(upperAlphabet))

          if (len_trim(word)<=0) return
          
          print *, 'In word <',word,'>:' 
          
          letterCount = countLetters(word)
          do j=1,len(upperAlphabet)
             if (letterCount(j)<=0) cycle
             print "(' letter ',a,' found ',i0,' times ')", upperAlphabet(j:j),letterCount(j)
          end do

      end subroutine printLettersInWord

      pure function countLetters(word) result(letterCount)
          character(len=*), intent(in) :: word
          integer :: letterCount(0:len(upperAlphabet))

          integer :: i,thisLetter

          letterCount = 0

          do i=1,len(word) 
             thisLetter = max(index(upperAlphabet,word(i:i)),index(lowerAlphabet,word(i:i)))
             letterCount(thisLetter) = letterCount(thisLetter)+1
          end do

      end function countLetters         

end program test_hello
```

That produces the following output:

```
 In word <hello>:
 letter E found 1 times
 letter H found 1 times
 letter L found 2 times
 letter O found 1 times
 In word <fortran>:
 letter A found 1 times
 letter F found 1 times
 letter N found 1 times
 letter O found 1 times
 letter R found 2 times
 letter T found 1 times
```

Comment: These _are_ useful intrinsic functions, but how would you consider applying them to the case of the question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all after looking at you code, I would suggest using IMPLICIT none. Also you have a few redundant variables which I have attempted to remove.

Also, in order to ensure each character is processed only once (which is your question), you need to have an additional do loop to check whether the next character string has already been processed. I have include a possible answer below, though have turned off the IMPLICIT feature but tried to keep in line with your coding style:

```
        PROGRAM MAIN
        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER :: N,I,J
        CHARACTER*8 CHAAR
        LOGICAL PROCCHAR
        CHAAR = "homework"

        DO I=1,8
          N=1
C ****    FIRST CHECK THIS CHARACTER HAS NOT BEEN PROCESSED ALREADY
          PROCCHAR = .TRUE.
          DO J=1,i-1
            IF(CHAAR(I:I) == CHAAR(J:J)) THEN
              PROCCHAR = .FALSE.
            ENDIF
          ENDDO
C ****    LOOK THROUGH REST OF CHARACTER STRING. BUT ONLY IF THIS
C         CHARACTER HAS NOT BEEN PROCESSED SO FAR
          DO J=i+1,8
            IF(CHAAR(I:I) == CHAAR(J:J).AND.PROCCHAR) THEN
C             AUX = CHAAR(J:J)
              N = N + 1
            ENDIF
          ENDDO
          IF(PROCCHAR) WRITE(*,*) 'CHARAACTER ',CHAAR(I:I),' OCCURS ',N
        ENDDO
        END
```